# Random blocks of data in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need to get random blocks of data from my data frame `df`.  I have tried using `df.sample(10)`, but it only generates individual samples, and not contiguous blocks.  Is there a way to sample random blocks (for instance, blocks of 6 continuous data points)?

Here is a sample of the data frame

```
Year_DoY_Hour
2015-11-20 12:00:00         NaN
2015-11-20 12:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 13:00:00         NaN
2015-11-20 13:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 14:00:00         NaN
2015-11-20 14:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 15:00:00    0.083298
  ...
2016-04-30 13:00:00    0.055639
2016-04-30 13:30:00    0.030809
2016-04-30 14:00:00    0.079277
2016-04-30 14:30:00    0.040736
2016-04-30 15:00:00    0.066980
2016-04-30 15:30:00    0.076448
2016-04-30 16:00:00    0.066822
2016-04-30 16:30:00    0.073143
2016-04-30 17:00:00         NaN
2016-04-30 17:30:00         NaN
2016-04-30 18:00:00         NaN
2016-04-30 18:30:00         NaN
2016-04-30 19:00:00         NaN
2016-04-30 19:30:00         NaN
```

So from `df` I need to create 3 randomly chosen blocks with 6 lines.

Example:

block1

```
2016-04-30 15:00:00    0.066980
2016-04-30 15:30:00    0.076448
2016-04-30 16:00:00    0.066822
2016-04-30 16:30:00    0.073143
2016-04-30 17:00:00         NaN
2016-04-30 17:30:00         NaN
```

block2

```
2016-04-30 09:30:00    0.036728
2016-04-30 10:00:00    0.036108
2016-04-30 10:30:00    0.031045
2016-04-30 11:00:00    0.031762
2016-04-30 11:30:00    0.033714
2016-04-30 12:00:00    0.042499
```

block3

```
2015-11-20 04:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 05:00:00         NaN
2015-11-20 05:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 06:00:00         NaN
2015-11-20 06:30:00         NaN
2015-11-20 07:00:00         NaN
```

Where the blocks should be in random order, but the data within the blocks must be in sequence. I have not found any function or anything like that to do this.

Comment: Can the blocks overlap?

Comment: I've read this 5 times in a row but I still don't understand what you are asking and what you are trying to achieve. Can you tell what you have now, what you want as an output and where is the problem? What are the two columns in the dataframe you are showing?

Comment: I think the idea is to extend `sample` but select blocks of consecutive rows instead of rows.

Comment: Blocks should not overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a random number from 0 to the length of the data frame, then slice the data frame at that index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a fake data frame
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2015-11-20', end='2016-04-30', freq='30min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=10, size=len(index)), index=index, columns=['vals'])

# set the block size and the number of samples
block_size = 6
num_samples = 3
samples = [df.iloc[x:x+block_size] for x in np.random.randint(len(df), size=num_samples)]

# check results
samples[0]
                          vals
2016-01-06 00:30:00  10.313824
2016-01-06 01:00:00   9.445082
2016-01-06 01:30:00  11.952581
2016-01-06 02:00:00   9.496415
2016-01-06 02:30:00  10.404322
2016-01-06 03:00:00   8.506910

samples[1]
                          vals
2015-12-23 02:00:00  10.472048
2015-12-23 02:30:00  10.276933
2015-12-23 03:00:00  10.013481
2015-12-23 03:30:00  11.293218
2015-12-23 04:00:00  10.258379
2015-12-23 04:30:00   9.543600

samples[2]
                          vals
2016-01-10 06:00:00  10.809594
2016-01-10 06:30:00   8.953594
2016-01-10 07:00:00  10.254928
2016-01-10 07:30:00   9.911142
2016-01-10 08:00:00  10.377016
2016-01-10 08:30:00  11.907871
```

Comment: I know its an old thread but i have question: Is there a way to this with replace=true?

Comment: as in a block of 10, but with replacements from that block?

Comment: This might yield results with less elements than `block_size`. It should be `np.random.randint(len(df) - block_size + 1`.

Comment: In this formulation, there is a possibility that some blocks overlap if two `x`'s are within `block_size` of each other. Is there a neat way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

This return a block of 6 consecutive entries or a smaller block if not consecutive entries were found:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]], index_col=0)

# define delta t
delta = pd.Timedelta('30min')

# sampling only 1 values
sample = df.sample(1)

# add 6 timesteps
istart = sample.index
iend = istart + 6*delta

# Loc it
df.loc[istart.values[0]:iend.values[0]]
```